# time complexity of constructing a BST using pre order

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search-tree, master-theorem

I tried to write a program to construct a binary search tree using the pre-order sequence. I know there are many solutions: the min/max algorithm, the classical (or "obvious" recursion) or even iteration rather than recursion.

I tried to implement the classical recursion: the first element of pre-order traversal is the root. Then I search for all elements which are less than the root. All these elements will be part of left subtree, and the other values will be part of the right subtree. I repeat that until I construct all substrees. It's a very classical approach.

Here is my code:

```
public static TreeNode constructInOrderTree(int[] inorder) { 
    return constructInOrderTree(inorder, 0, inorder.length-1);
}

 private static TreeNode constructInOrderTree(int[] inorder, int start, int end){
 if(start>end){
        return null;
 }

int rootValue = inorder[start];
TreeNode root = new TreeNode(rootValue);

int k = 0; 
for (int i =0; i< inorder.length; i++){
    if (inorder[i]<= rootValue){ 
        k=i;
    }
}

 root.left = constructInOrderTree(inorder, start+1, k);
 root.right= constructInOrderTree(inorder, k+1, end);

    return root;
   }
```

My question is: **What is the time complexity of this algorithm? Is it O(n^2) or O(n * log(n) ) ?**

I searched here in stackoverflow but I found many contradictory answers. Sometimes, someone said that it is O(n^2), sometime O(n*log(n)) and I got really confused.

Can we apply the master theorem here? If yes, "perhaps" we can consider that each time we divide the tree in two subtrees (of equal parts), so we will have the relation:  (O(n) is the complexity of searching in the array)

T(n) = 1/2 * T(n/2)  + O(n)

Which will give us a complexity of `O(n*log(n))`. But, it's not really true I think, we **don't** divide the tree at equal parts because we search in the array until we found the adequate elements no?

Is it possible to apply the master theorem here?

Answer (score 1):

**Forethoughts:**

No, it is neither `O(n^2)`, nor `O(nlogn)` in WC. Because of the nature of trees and the fact that you don't perform any complex actions on each element. All you do is output it, in contrast to sorting it with some comparison algorithm.

Then the WC would be `O(n)`.

That is when the tree is skewed, i.e. one of the root's subtrees is empty. Then you have quasi a simple linked list. Then to output it you must visit each element at least once giving `O(n)`.

**Proof:**

Lets assume the right subtree is empty and the per call effort is constant(only print out). Then

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(0) + c
T(n) = T(n-2) + 2T(0) + 2c
.
.
T(n) = nT(0) + nc = n(T(0) + c)
```

Since `T(0)` and `c` are constants, you end up in `O(n)`.